# ObjectDataProvider MethodParameter define directly in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

I am trying to modify the MethodParameter directly in the XAML.  I do have a working example where I am setting it from code.  Code version is:

```
Dim odp As New ObjectDataProvider()
odp = FindResource("Products")
odp.MethodParameters.Clear()
odp.MethodParameters.Add(CType(txtCatId.Text, Integer))
```

ObjectDataProvider defined in XAML looks like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Products"
      ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ProductsDataProvider}"
      MethodName="GetProdsByCatID">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Is there anyway I can retrieve the value of my textbox (which is bound to a separate ObjectDataProvider and put that in place of the hardcoded "0" currently in my XAML?  I am looking to have this be completely XAML driven and have not been able to get it working without the code change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to bind TextBox.Text like this

```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Products"
      ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ProductsDataProvider}"
      MethodName="GetProdsByCatID">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

   <TextBox Text={Binding Source={StaticResource Products}, Path="MethodParameters[0]" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" Mode="OneWayToSource"}/>
```

if you have other bindings to TextBox.Text try to user MultiBinding

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
      <MultiBinding Converter="...">
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Products}", Path="MethodParameters[0]" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        ...
      </MultiBinding>
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: The property "Text" is not found in Type "Binding".  Is that syntax correct?

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be Source="{StaticResource... ? There is still a syntax issue.

Comment: yea, it should, I change it yet, I didn't try it, I just give you an Idea, how to try to do it

Comment: Ok still not working.  I am looking into it further, but if it points me in the right direction I will return to give you the credit.